# unknown command error while posting files to solr

Tags: solr

I am trying to post the following json format of the file to solr

`{"userName": "Bill", "stars": 4, "review_id": "-TsVN230RCkLYKBeLsuz7A", "type": "review", "business_name": "Eric Goldberg, MD", "user_id": "zvJCcrpm2yOZrxKffwGQLA", "text": "Dr. Goldberg has been my doctor for years and I like him.  I've found his office to be fairly efficient.  Today I actually got to see the doctor a few minutes early!  \n\nHe seems very engaged with his patients and his demeanor is friendly, yet authoritative.    \n\nI'm glad to have Dr. Goldberg as my doctor."}`

However I get the error

`Response: {"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":32},"                                                                                                                error":{"msg":"Unknown command 'user_name' at [12]","code":400}}`

while I am trying to do

`post.sh -c coreName fileName.json`

This is driving me crazy. I have unloaded the core and created it again to see if previous attempts to post files is causing this error. But that did not help.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm getting a similar error, it keeps saying "Unknown command 'requestKey' at [13]" and yet i have no requestKey field anywhere in my request

Answer (score 11):

Solr is looking for a command (like 'add') when you send an object, so you need to either add the command, as such:

```
{"add": {"doc":{"userName": "Bill", "stars": 4, "review_id": "-TsVN230RCkLYKBeLsuz7A", "type": "review", "business_name": "Eric Goldberg, MD", "user_id": "zvJCcrpm2yOZrxKffwGQLA", "text": "Dr. Goldberg has been my doctor for years and I like him.  I've found his office to be fairly efficient.  Today I actually got to see the doctor a few minutes early!  \n\nHe seems very engaged with his patients and his demeanor is friendly, yet authoritative.    \n\nI'm glad to have Dr. Goldberg as my doctor."}}}
```

Or place it in an array:

```
[{"userName": "Bill", "stars": 4, "review_id": "-TsVN230RCkLYKBeLsuz7A", "type": "review", "business_name": "Eric Goldberg, MD", "user_id": "zvJCcrpm2yOZrxKffwGQLA", "text": "Dr. Goldberg has been my doctor for years and I like him.  I've found his office to be fairly efficient.  Today I actually got to see the doctor a few minutes early!  \n\nHe seems very engaged with his patients and his demeanor is friendly, yet authoritative.    \n\nI'm glad to have Dr. Goldberg as my doctor."}]
```

See also: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON